# How to add extra text to a value mid-print

Tags: python

I am modifying the print function like:

```py
cg = "\u001b[32;1m"
stop = "\u001b[0m"

_print = print
def print(*args, **kw):
  #color the word "CommandGeek" green
  args = (arg.replace('CommandGeek', f'{cg}CommandGeek{stop}') if isinstance(arg, str) else arg for arg in args)

  _print(*args, **kw)
```

What I want to do is add some code like so:

```py
cg = "\u001b[32;1m"
stop = "\u001b[0m"

_print = print
def print(*args, **kw):
   #color the word "CommandGeek" green
   args = (arg.replace('CommandGeek', f'{cg}CommandGeek{stop}') if isinstance(arg, str) else arg for arg in args)
   
   #Color entire the message green if "CommandGeek:" is in it.
   if "CommandGeek:" in args:
      args = cg + args + stop

  _print(*args, **kw)
```

But this doesn't work, and it just prints nothing. I also tried to just put in the if statement without the modification to args, and it still did nothing. What is happening here, and how do I change the value that will be printed if "CommandGeek:" is in the message?

Comment: `args` is of the type `tuple` but you change it to a generator expression via your `replace()` line. I'm guessing that is your issue.

Comment: @Take_Care_ no, your suggestion is actually invalid syntax. Just try it, it will error. The asker's syntax is correct. They just need to wrap the generator with `tuple()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without advanced constructs like generator, list-comprehension or similar.

#### Understanding the asterisk (unpacking) and tuples

First we need to understand that `*args` is a parameter named `args` defined as *varargs* (multiple parameters as *tuple*). See
[What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66856940/5730279) which explains it very well:

> Using `*args` in the function signature packs all of the positional arguments into a single tuple args. If you then say `*args` in another function call within your the function body, it spreads it back into multiple arguments, [..]

#### Why it is used here?

This is used in your function definition `def print(*args, **kw):` to mimic the same signature (parameters) as the built-in [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function, originally in Python. With the re-definition `_print = print` before this can be seen as interceptor.

The effect will be a `print` function that automatically highlights words or output using ANSI-colors ([ANSI-escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)) when certain keyword (here "CommandGeek" found).

#### Your task

Implement the comments (tasks) inside the function body:

```py
   #color the word "CommandGeek" green
       # locate the word
       # surround it with ANSI-color code

   #Color entire the message green if "CommandGeek:" is in it.
       # locate the word
       # surround the entire message with ANSI-color code
```

Your input (the message(s) containing words or commands) is given by parameter `*args` which we know is to pack all positional arguments into a tuple (*varargs*). The tuple is named `args`.

```py
GREEN = "\u001b[32;1m"
RESET = "\u001b[0m"
WORD = "CommandGeek"

# a testable function with debug-prints
def color(*args):
    print(len(args))
    colored = []
    for a in args:
        s = str(a)
        if s.__contains__(WORD):
            print("Found it in: " + s)
            colored.append(s.replace(WORD, f"{GREEN}{WORD}{RESET}"))
        else:
            colored.append(a)
    return colored

colored = color('Hello', 'World', 'CommandGeek')
print(colored)  # prints the list or tuple (not colored)
print(*colored)  # prints all with color if found (because unpacked)
```

Prints (bold was originally green in console):

> 3
>
> Found it in: CommandGeek
>
> Hello World **CommandGeek**

Now we have one word colored.
Next let's color the entire message (= all args) if at least one contains the word.

```py
GREEN = "\u001b[32;1m"
RESET = "\u001b[0m"
WORD = "CommandGeek"

def contains_word(*args):
    for a in args:
        s = str(a)
        if s.__contains__(WORD):
            return True
    return False

tuple = ('Hello', 'World', 'CommandGeek')  # define a tuple
should_color = contains_word(*tuple)  # unpack a tuple as multiple args (varargs)
if should_color:
    print(GREEN, *tuple, RESET)  # prints all elements in color (unpacked)
else:
    print(*tuple)  # prints the tuple (unpacked, not colored)
```

Prints (bold was originally green in console):

> ** Hello World CommandGeek**

---

Update: complete solution (fixed leading space)

```py
GREEN = "\u001b[32;1m"
RESET = "\u001b[0m"
KEYWORD = "CommandGeek"


def color_word(*args):
    colored = []
    for a in args:
        if isinstance(a, str):
            colored.append(a.replace(KEYWORD, f"{GREEN}{KEYWORD}{RESET}"))
        else:
            colored.append(a)
    return colored

print(*color_word('Hello', 1, 'World', True, '_CommandGeek_'))


def contains_word(*args):
    for a in args:
        if str(a).__contains__("CommandGeek"):
            return True
    return False

def color_message(*args):
    if contains_word(*args):  # unpack a tuple as multiple args (varargs)
        # surround tuples with color-code and reset-code
        colored = (f"{GREEN}{args[0]}",) + args[1:]  # prepend to first element (new colored tuple)
        colored = colored[0:-1] + (f"{colored[-1]}{RESET}",)  # and append on last element (replace colored tuple)
        return colored
    return args

print(*color_message('Hello', 1, 'World', True, '_CommandGeek_'))
print(*color_message('Hello: CommandGeek'))
```

Prints on a console supporting ANSI-colors:

[image: screenshot of console output]

---

#### Further reading

- Real Python: [Python args and kwargs: Demystified](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#unpacking-with-the-asterisk-operators)
- [Decorating Python's builtin print() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658639/decorating-pythons-builtin-print-function), shows how module [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) can be used to e.g. `builtin.print()` when redefining the original name locally
- [How do I print colored output with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473297/how-do-i-print-colored-output-with-python-3), suggesting 3rd-party modules [`colorama`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) or [`termcolor`](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/)
- StackAbuse (2021): [How to Print Colored Text in Python](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python/) with beautiful illustrations

Comment: I have tested both snippets .. we can debate about `print(green, *tuple, clear)` because the leading space ️

Comment: About the ```print(green, *tuple, clear)```, It also prints a space before the message. So ```print("CommandGeek: message")``` prints ```" CommandGeek: message"```. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @Blackhole927 Yes, exactly the prepending space because of built-in `print` default space separator! To fix it: add the ANSI-escape codes not as extra element, but as prefix and suffix to the first and last tuple which can also be a single. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: @Blackhole927 Fixed the space-issue, refined, updated (see between horizontal-rulers)

Answer (score 0):

When you do the replacement, you're setting `args` to a generator expression, since you're using [generator expression syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). `args` needs to be a `tuple`. All you have to do is add the word `tuple` to the front of the statement and it will work just fine:

```
args = tuple(arg.replace('CommandGeek', f'{cg}CommandGeek{stop}') if isinstance(arg, str) else arg for arg in args)
```

To test this I did:

```
cg = "_Testing_"
stop = "_123_"

_print = print
def print(*args, **kw):
   #color the word "CommandGeek" green
   args = tuple(arg.replace('CommandGeek', f'{cg}CommandGeek{stop}') if isinstance(arg, str) else arg for arg in args)
   
   #Color entire the message green if "CommandGeek:" is in it.
   if "CommandGeek:" in args:
      args = cg + args + stop
   
   _print(*args, **kw)
  
print('Test CommandGeek Test','CommandGeek','BlahBlah')
```

Output:

```
Test _Testing_CommandGeek_123_ Test _Testing_CommandGeek_123_ BlahBlah
```

Comment: The testing can also be done with ANSI-color codes (if your console supports them) ️ But agree, for visualizing the output here, monochrome (pseudo-)markup is very suitable ️